# Round() does not return an integer raster in R

Tags: raster, r

I want to convert the datatype of a raster to integer. For example:

```
x <- raster(nrow=10,ncol=10)
```

its datatype is float

```
dataType(x)
[1] "FLT4S"
```

then I round the pixel values of *x* by

```
 y <- round(x)
 dataType(y)
 [1] "FLT4S"
```

How can I change the dataType of *y* to int?

Answer (score 10):

Just tell it:

```
> dataType(y)="INT4S"
> dataType(y)
[1] "INT4S"
```

read the help for `dataType` to make sure you are doing the right thing though. This doesn't change R's internal storage mode:

```
> x=raster(nrow=10,ncol=10)
> x[]=runif(100)
> mean(x[])
[1] 0.5444336
> dataType(x)="INT4U"
> dataType(x)
[1] "INT4U"
> mean(x[])
[1] 0.5444336
```

If what you *really* meant to ask was "how do I change the underlying storage type of raster data" then possibly you can just change the storage mode of the appropriate values:

```
> r = raster(ncol=100,nrow=100)
> r[]=rnorm(100*100)
> object.size(r)
86460 bytes
> storage.mode(r[]) = "integer"
> object.size(r)
46460 bytes
> r[][1:10]
 [1]  0  0 -1 -1 -1 -1  0  0 -2  0
```

Or just coerce the values:

```
> r[]=rnorm(100*100)
> storage.mode(r[])
[1] "double"
> r[]=as.integer(r[])
> storage.mode(r[])
[1] "integer"
```

Comment: What I want is to actually change the internal storage mode so to reduce memory requirements. It is not efficient to reserve 4 bytes in memory for a pixel when 1 byte would be sufficient.

Comment: Done, see edits

Comment: Hmm. When I try any of these, then import a raster saved as a .tif from R into Arcmap, I am left with a floating point raster still.

Comment: How are you saving the raster? I'd guess you are not specifying `datatype="INT4U"` or some other integer specification in `writeRaster`. The default is `"FLT4S"`.

Comment: Aha. So I must specify datatype="INT4U" within writeRaster, not only as in the code block above. Fair enough!

Comment: yes, and notice its `datatype` in `writeRaster` but `dataType` to get the type of a raster...